# Facebook like count after change domain

Tags: blogger

Well, did everythin that I could to get my facebook like count back after changing domain into blogger but couldn't.

Now, maybe I have some kind of light since I made it work a bit. Here it goes.

This is my facebook like button:

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.canonicalUrl + &quot;&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px !important;'/>
```

Since it uses the "data:post.canonicalUrl" to get the posts URL, this facebook button will always track my new domain, not the old one.

But, if I change it to my old domain "portaldascoisas.com.br" it starts to work, showing my old page count.

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + &quot;http://portaldascoisas.com.br/&quot; + &quot;&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=21&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px !important;'/>
```

But this will make my posts count show my page count, and all my counts will have the same number.
Now I need to find a way to get the last URL portion into blogger to make it work.
"data:post.url" won't work, since it will give me the whole URL and I just need the url without the domain.

Anyone has a solution?